# Raspberry Pi - Time changed back and 45 days of data lost

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, raspbian

My first question ever on Stack Overflow so bear with me! :)

I made a bash script on my RPI for cloning the SD (using the DD command) after stopping all critical services (apache2, mysql and cron) to a connected USB hard drive and it seem to work (the file.img was made, but is not working), after the script was done the RPI lost ethernet connection I had to make a hard reboot by removing the power cable. After I plugged it back in the Raspberry rebooted fine, but all data for the last 45 days are just gone!

Blog posts 45 days back in wordpress was lost, the folders and files I made on the SD card for 45 days back was lost. So I can't show you the script I made and I can't show you any log information there is a big gap between the 10th of January 20:44:39 and at the "new" start 24th of February 07:24:07. The first log post on the 24th Feb in the syslog is:

```
Feb 24 07:24:07 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Time has been changed
Feb 24 07:24:08 raspberrypi dhcpcd[434]: eth0: no IPv6 Routers available
Feb 24 07:38:47 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Feb 24 07:38:47 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Feb 24 08:03:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting user-1001.slice.
Feb 24 08:03:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Created slice user-1001.slice.
Feb 24 08:03:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1001...
Feb 24 08:03:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Session c1 of user pi.
Feb 24 08:03:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Session c1 of user pi.
```

I have never experienced this before and I can't find anything on the web about this problem.

NOW TO THE QUESTION:
What the h*ll happen and is there any way to recover the lost data???

Thank you all in advanced!!

Comment: Could you mix the device files and dd to your SD card? Then it would explain how this could happen and answer "no" to the question whether it can be restored.

Comment: @dmi Hi, thanks for your answer. The script was pretty basic, it check if the hard drive was mounted, then stopped services and I made a variable for the time stamp before running the dd command and I tested it before running anything else. The file on the hard drive is named backup_20170223190322.img. The dd command was written like sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/mnt/backup_$timestamp.img After the dd command I had services start, but they never started, everything just "died". Then I rebooted.

Comment: Self-cloning the whole SD card while the OS is running on it sounds like a recipe designed to result in unpredictable problems, a must-avoid tactic - and it sounds as though you hadn't tested the process out for 45 days(!) before relying on it, another must-avoid tactic. Good luck, and suggest you avoid must-avoid tactics and test your process BEFORE relying on it to keep valuable data.